# Is 'require' preferrable to 'autoload' with Ruby 2 in a multi-process fork server?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, fork, copy-on-write

I am reading [this](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/08/eager-loading-for-greater-good/) article. My concern is the benefits of `autoload` vs `require`. From reading the article, what I gather is that using `autoload` for multi-threaded servers is bad because one thread might try to load an object that is not in memory yet.

The article says what about multi-process servers? Is autoload good for those? Then it says it depends. If the server uses fork (which spawns a new process for each request), such as Phusion Passenged, and you are using Ruby 2, then autoload is not beneficial.

The reason is because Ruby 2 uses copy-on-write semantics. This means it is better to use `require` than `autoload`. With copy-on-write semantics, if we load `Foo::Bar` on boot, we will have one copy of `Foo::Bar` shared between all processes. Hence, there will be no big memory footprint.

However, if we are not using Ruby 2 and we are not using a multi-process server that uses fork, each process will end up loading its own copy of `Foo::Bar` possibly leading to higher memory usage. Therefore, in that case `autoload` is preferrable to `require`.

Is my interpretation of the article correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got it, but it would be good to restate a couple of points to be clear:

1. The important distinction isn't quite between `require` and `autoload` but between eager and lazy loading. Eager loading is thread-safe and memory efficient when forking, but it slows server startup. Lazy loading is neither thread-safe nor memory efficent when forking, but it allows fast server startup. `require` or `autoload` together with Rails `eager_autoload` eager load; `autoload` by itself lazy loads.
2. With the above in mind, different servers and Ruby versions raise different issues for lazy and eager loading:

   - In a threading server, lazy loading is unsafe, so eager loading is (ahem) required.
   - In an evented server, lazy loading is fine, so you might as well lazy-load for fast server startup.
   - In a forking server, lazy loading is safe but memory-inefficient.

     - In Ruby < 2, eager loading is also memory-inefficient, since Ruby < 2 doesn't support copy-on-write. So you might as well load lazily. (Actually, what you should do is upgrade to current Ruby.)
     - In Ruby >= 2, eager loading is memory-efficient, since it takes advantage of copy-on-write, and therefore preferred.